# apt bower and ember install concerns

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm a new Ubuntu 18.04 user. I was trying to download bower and ember, however when I typed bower or ember into the terminal Ubuntu suggested that I type `sudo apt install bower` or `sudo apt install ember`. When I ran these commands in the terminal they installed packages that didn't do anything useful, and I'm concerned that the commands were unsuccessful or maybe I didn't install the right packages.

The bower package said that it needed to change system settings when downloaded. I just ignored it since I thought that was what I needed.

Bower didn't really do anything, but ember made a screen pop-up that I could not escape without turning my computer off.

Comment: For an explanation of the reason for the weird ember pop-up please read the 5th comment below the accepted answer.

Comment: @karel I've retracted my close vote for this question (& deleted 'possible duplicate' comment) after seeing how multiple edits fundamentally changed it. Nice answer and thanks for pinging me over in Unix&Linux SE, should be all good now.

Comment: @Fabby The suggested duplicate question matches the question's title and body text, but it doesn't succeed in explaining how to answer this question because the accepted answer to this question is one level deeper down than any of the answers to the suggested duplicate question. A better way to match would be to find a duplicate that answers the question rather than superficially natural language processing the question's body text which only generates a list of search results similar to the way Google search does.

Comment: @karel: Duplicate vote retracted and your comment upvoted so the next person in line in the CV queue will see it better...  **;-)**

Comment: So far I have counted 4 close votes on this question and 3 out of the 4 close votes retracted, so I think that this question will probably stay open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bower is a snap package in Ubuntu 18.04. Bower is a package manager for the web. Bower can be installed/uninstalled from the Ubuntu Software app or from the terminal with `sudo snap install bower --classic`.

Ember is a Node.js package in Ubuntu 18.04 that can be installed by `npm install -g ember-cli`. This is probably the correct Ember package for you to install. To verify that your installation was successful, run `ember -v` . Adding Ember to your application with Bower is easy; simply run `bower install ember --save` . For Ember Data, run bower install `ember-data --save` .

The ember apt package in Ubuntu has nothing to do with Bower or Node.js, so it's probably useless to you and can be safely uninstalled with `sudo apt remove ember` .

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the correct package. I was just concerned that the earlier packages might be stuck on my machine. I did sudo apt remove ember and bower and it worked fine. But what was apt install ember supposed to do? As well as apt install bower?

Comment: `apt install ember` was a mistake, so remove the ember apt package with `sudo apt remove ember`. There is no Bower apt package in the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories, so the safest thing to do is install the Bower snap package instead with `sudo snap install bower --classic` .

Comment: Does `sudo snap install bower` request system controls for you? When I tried it it told me that it needed access to system hardware.

Comment: Also, why is the `apt install ember` package even there if it doesn't do anything helpful? What is its purpose for existing?

Comment: Run `sudo snap install bower --classic` not `sudo snap install bower` and it will install without an error message. ember.js is a component-service application framework written in JavaScript. Ember is a 3D client framework for WorldForge. Same name, different app entirely.

Comment: Ah, okay. I feel much safer now that I understand the purpose of these packages. Much appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

Since the packages are downloaded via apt/snap using Ubuntu's official repository, it must be safe. Viruses are generally from third party ppa(s) or repositories.